# Specifying Multiple Query Parameters in http:outbound endpoint in Mule

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, mule, query-string

In my Mule-config.xml, I do a http post to a service using 2 query parameters...I tried to add 2 query parameters like this:

```
<http:outbound-endpoint
           address="http://${server.user}:${server.passwd}@${server.host}:${server.port}/DebtService/debt/sendemail?appId=#[header:SESSION:appId]&debtId=#[header:SESSION:debtId]"
```

but mule throws out this error while starting

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The reference to entity "debtId" must end with the ';' delimiter.
```

If I just have one query parameter, then it all works well, but if I add second query parameter using '&' the above error is thrown...

Any ideas on what am i doing wrong here...
Advance thanks..

Comment: The syntax `#[header:SESSION:appId]` is _old_. If you're on 3.3.0 or better, use `#[sessionVars.appId]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's invalid XML: use `&amp;` instead of `&`.

Comment: Thank you...this worked...does mule need it like this only for '&' or any other charecters too?

Comment: Nothing to do with Mule: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML